# To find the value of a function at a point where it is continuous

Tags: limits, continuity

Find $f(0)$ so that the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{x^4}$ is continuous everywhere.

My attempt:

By applying sandwich theorem $-1 \le \cos(x) \le 1$.

$$1 \ge -\cos(x) \ge -1$$

$$2 \ge 1-\cos(x) \ge 0$$

$\cos(x)$ is a decreasing function from $0^\circ$ to $90^\circ$.

$$\cos(2) \le \cos(1-\cos(x)) \le 1$$

$$-\cos(2) \ge -\cos(1-\cos(x)) \ge -1$$

$$1-\cos(2) \ge 1-\cos(1-\cos(x)) \ge 0$$

$$\frac{(1-\cos(2))}{(x^4)} \ge \frac{(1-\cos(1-\cos(x)))}{(x^4)} \ge 0$$

Thus I got the answer 0 applying limits every where.
But the actual answer is 1/8 apparently. How?

Comment: I really didn't know anything about MathJax or LaTex.Sorry it's so vague.

Comment: Do you know about finite expansions?

Comment: yes I do know about them.

Comment: Just ask [alpha](http://wolfr.am/4cNz6LQk).

Comment: You need to apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Be careful that $2$ is greater than $90$ degrees, so your conclusion there is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use The fact that near $0$: $$\cos(u) \sim 1 - \frac{u^2}{2!}$$

So that after applying the finite expansion of $\cos$ near $0$ twice, you get:

$$1 - \cos(1 - \cos(x)) \sim \frac{x^4}{8}$$

Then the $x^4$'s cancel each other.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to note that $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{1-\cos y}{y^2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now you write
$$ \frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{x^4}= \frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{(1-\cos x)^2}\left( \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\right)^2 \to \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{8}$$